# Chrome adobe flash player blocked and swf files

Tags: google-chrome, flash

I have a website  which uses adobe flash player and download swf files. I get the error

```
Blocked the following complements

Adobe Flash Player
```

I allow websites run flash in Chrome settings.

How can I allow download swf files in Chrome?

How can I allow run flash Adobe Player?

Comment: _"I have a website"_ show a link to an example page that recreates the problem or show html code of how you embed your SWF (Flash apps) file.

Comment: I'm an user or this website.

Comment: As a user, all  you can do is your _"I allow websites run flash in Chrome settings."_ after that it's the mistake(s) of page creator if they cannot get Flash embedded like how Chrome expects.